# Azure AD authentication error AADSTS50005 on Linux

Tags: linux, azure-active-directory, chromium

I'm using Chromium and FireFox browser on Linux. Out of blue my application started throwing Azure Active Directory Authentication error [AADSTS50005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes).

Error definition AADSTS50005 states:

> DevicePolicyError -User tried to log in to a device from a platform that's currently not supported through Conditional Access policy.*

The message is clear Linux platform is not supported. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this problem was to run Chromium in supported platform (iOS, Android, Mac or Windows) firefox Add-On

### Chromium:

Execute below steps in **Chromium** browser.

1. Press `F12` key.
2. Press `Esc` key.
3. Click `Network conditions` tab, and unchecked `User browser default` checkbox. Choose Chrome on supported by Azure AD platform e.g. Windows. Choose `Chrome --Windows`
   [image]

### FireFox:

Execute below steps in **FireFox** browser, or install [User-Agent Switcher and Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-string-switcher/) add-on.

1. Press `Ctl+l`, type `about:config` and click `Accept the Risk and Continue` button.
2. In search type `general.useragent.override` make sure `String` radio button is selected, next click `Add` button (plus icon).
   [image]
3. From [User Agent by OS list](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/operating_system_name/) click OS that you want to emulate, e.g. Windows. and select agent that interests you the most. I chose `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36`. Copy it, and paste it to `general.useragent.override` and click `Save` button.

Comment: You aren't technically running it on a supported platform though right? This is changing the text that is sent in the User-Agent header to make the service think you are running on a supported platform?

Comment: @juunas You nailed it. This is exactly what I do. I pretend to be different user agent.